# Can you fully upgrade a car in Mafia 3?

Tags: mafia-3

Can you fully upgrade a car in Mafia 3?

I know you can do somethings like upgrade suspension and make the car bullet proof, but can you change the colour, the tires, the wheels etc. like you can in mafia 2?

Can do this after a certain point in the story or in a specific place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are currently no options for the sort of vehicle modification you are looking for however the developer has confirmed on there website that additional options for the cosmetic modification of vehicles will be available via free DLC at some point after release.

See the quote from the developers website below for additional details.

> **MORE Vehicle Customization**
>
> Hey, gearheads: We’ll be expanding upon the vehicle upgrades that
>   already exist in Mafia III by adding new customization options. You
>   can cherry out your favorite ride with new wheels, personalized
>   license plates, and paint jobs. And, yes, you will get even more
>   options to boost the performance on your vehicles.

[Source](https://mafiagame.com/en/news/view/en-a-look-at-the-post-release-content-coming-to-mafia-3/)